# Matching Multiple Groups in a Java-Regex

Tags: java, regex

Is it possible to find all groups in a regular expression that match a specific part of a String?

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(green trousers)|(green\\s+t)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("my beautiful green trousers are red!");
    while (matcher.find()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            if (matcher.group(i) != null) {
                System.out.println("group " + i + " matched");
            }
        }
    }
```

This example only returns the first group as matching, but I also interested in the fact that the second group matches too.

Comment: No, that's not how regex works. You would have to check 2 different patterns to see if they both match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no direct way to do this, a regular expression will consume the string from left to right until it finds a match.

Using `|` means it will first check for the first alternative, if that doesn't match it backtracks and tries the second alternative. In this case `(green trousers)` matches, so the searching stops and the match is returned.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to check all cases within a single regular expression, however, there are constructs that allow you to check if more than one subpattern matches for a particular substring, and these are so called »zero width assertions« (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum), under »Special constructs«)

Example:

```
"(?=[ab]{5})[bc]{5}"
```

will only match on `bbbbb`